# How can I make preferences boxes open in correct display with SecondBar?

Tags: display, menu-bar

I've just started using SecondBar to provide a menubar for applications that I display in an external monitor. It's a big help, except for one thing: dialog boxes (like Apple Menu -> System Preferences, or Firefox's add-ins) open in the main display.

Is there any way to make dialog boxes open in whichever display the menubar was clicked from? So that if I use the main Mac menu bar for apps in my main display, the dialog opens in the main display, and if I use the SecondBar menu in my external display the dialog opens in the external display?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with how SecondBar works, but it looks like it's just a hack that duplicates the menubar on an external monitor. There's no operating system support for a second menubar so no support for determining which menubar was clicked and which monitor to open the dialog in.

*Perhaps* the developer of SecondBar could somehow intercept the command and redirect the dialog, but I really doubt this low-level jiggery-pokery is possible.

Comment: See, that's the kind of thing that makes me really scratch my head when people extoll the virtues of the Mac UI. In my mind, an application's menu bar belongs with the application. If the application is displayed on a second monitor, the menubar should display on the second monitor as well. It should not be integrated into the OS to such a degree that all configuration, preferences, etc. that you work with for an application would be happening on a different monitor than you are actually viewing the application on.

Comment: SecondBar IS a hack - it's not perfect, because the menubar is duplicating what's on the main monitor. So if I have Thunderbird open in my first monitor, and Chrome open in my second monitor, the way I'd expect it to work (and the way it works in every other OS I've worked with) is that the menubar for Thunderbird is available in the first monitor, and the menubar for Chrome is available in the second monitor.

Comment: What SecondBar does is duplicates the menubar for the *active* application. So if I have Thunderbird open in 1 and Chrome open in 2, and Chrome is my "active" application, I see the menubar for Chrome in both monitors. It's better than nothing, because at least I don't have to change monitors to access the menubar for Chrome, but I do have to switch to deal with any dialogs. That's just ludicrous design as far as I'm concerned. 

(Didn't mean to turn this into a rant against Macs; I'm just finding it very frustrating after Linux, which lets me configure all these things however I want.)

Comment: "In my mind, an application's menu bar belongs with the application." This is true. However, in Mac OS X, the desktop *spans all monitors*. You cannot say "if the application is displayed on a second monitor" because an application can have multiple windows. Try opening two windows in Safari, put one in one monitor and one in the other. How does the OS know which "window" the application is in? It doesn't care, it only cares which monitor you made default by placing the menu bar.

Comment: "the way I'd expect it to work (and the way it works in every other OS I've worked with)" -- every other OS you've worked with probably has multiple menu bars *attached to each application window*. Mac OS has always been designed with the concept of a single menu bar *for all applications* attached to the main monitor.

Comment: There are many advantages to a single menu approach: fixed position on screen, adherence to Fitt's Law, reduces confusion for novice users, simplicity, doesn't waste space as multiple menu bars per windows does…

Comment: "There are many advantages to a single menu approach". And there are just as many disadvantages, which become more and more obvious as people start to work with multiple monitors. I understand your point, I just think that an OS that touts itself as so user-friendly and well designed should give me the option of how I want my menubars to behave if I have multiple monitors.

Comment: Having menu bars attached to windows would break application-centric design of MacOS. You could no longer have an application open with no document windows. If you allowed users a choice, you would have to design applications from the ground up to target two different modes: application-centric, or window-centric. This would double the complexity of the operating system, and double users' confusion.

Comment: If you're interested in more discussion on this topic, see this Ars Technica forum: http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=248668

Comment: "You could no longer have an application open with no document windows." That's another thing that drives me crazy... I close all the windows of a specific app, and yet it's still open. I guess I just assumed since OSX was supposed to be based on Unix that things would work more like the various Linux distros I've worked with. Oh, well. I'm stuck with Mac at work, so I guess I just have to suck it up and deal.